# Создание таблицы в WX на haskell

Tags: haskell, wxwidgets

Бьюсь над программирование графического интерфейса. Что-то получается, но возник такой вопрос.
Как можно сделать таблицу не просто с текстовыми полями, а когда одно поле - выбор из списка, другое поле чекбокс.
Нашёл пример http://d.hatena.ne.jp/sirocco/20130824/1377329359
но он у меня вываливается с ошибкой вида
[image]

когда пытаюсь сменить чек бокс, а выпадающий список вообще не работает.

Возникло подозрение, что этот функционал в модуле wxHaskell не реализован. Как создаются свои виджеты, не знаю ни на C++ ни на haskell. Это попутный вопрос т.е. как создавать свои виджеты на wxHaskell.